# 16.04 New Install won't connect to wifi

Tags: networking, wireless

Did a fresh install of 16.04 and can see my wifi router as well as my neighbors'.  When I put in the password, it won't connect and asks for the password again.  Searched the web for answers:

1. Tried the fix to stop the mac address changes,
2. Restarted network-manager a bunch of times,
3. Made sure the wireless driver was updated.
4. Tried a usb install of 12.04; it wouldn't connect
   either.

Output of `lspci` command:

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82566MC Gigabit Network Connection [8086:104d] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 82566MC Gigabit Network Connection [17aa:20ba]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 [8086:2834] (rev 03)
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection [8086:4227] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection [8086:1010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwl3945
    Kernel modules: iwl3945
15:00.0 CardBus bridge [0607]: Ricoh Co Ltd RL5c476 II [1180:0476] (rev b6)
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Added a post where I linked to the output file for the wireless-info script.

Tried to start the wifi using nmtui but it did the same thing.

Tried to copy and paste the password into network-manager, no difference.

See my comments below on the stuff I tried tonight.

Comment: Post network log

Comment: What happens when you type (from a command terminal) `nmcli con wifi  con [name of wifi network]`, replacing "[name of wifi network]" with the name of the network you want to connect to. (They may only work on 16.04.) Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Comes back and says at the bottom   'wifi' is not valid 'connection' command

Comment: @AmrAyman where is this network log? Jim Snider, we most likely need hardware information. Run the [wireless info script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and [edit] your question to post the results, please

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Here's the output from the wireless info script    http://paste.ubuntu.com/25784636/

Comment: Tried reinstalling the bcmwl-kernel-source and same results.....still keeps asking for the password.

Comment: Tried removing and reinstalling network-manager, no luck

Comment: Tried the nmcli c up SSID but still asks for the password over and over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-installed 16.04 last night with one big change.  Found out that my router was set for 802.11n only.  Reset it to allow older connections and wifi worked just fine.